# Python Replace elements in a list that are also in another list, and delete others

Tags: python, list, enumerate

I would like to make a replacement on elements of the list `l1` that are also in `l2`, and delete elements that are not in `l2`. I don't understand why the following solution does not work: it returns

```
[33, 33, 'd']
```

instead of:

```
[33, 33, '33']
```

Here is my solution:

```
l1=['a','b','c', 'd']
l2= ['a','b','d','f']
for (i,wor) in enumerate(l1):
    if wor in l2:
        l1[i]= 33
    else:
        del l1[i]
```

Comment: What about it isn't working?  That's usually helpful to see to try to fix things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add some `print` calls to see what happens:

```
l1=['a','b','c', 'd']
l2= ['a','b','d','f']
for (i,wor) in enumerate(l1):
    if wor in l2:
        l1[i]= 33
    else:
        del l1[i]
    print(i, len(l1))
```

prints:

```
0 4
1 4
2 3
```

The index keeps going according to the original `l1` but you changed the size of `l1`during iteration. This messes everything up. You should not do this.

Answer (score 1):

Use a set to store the l2 elements and just replace elements that are in the set with 33:

```
l1=['a','b','c', 'd']
l2= ['a','b','d','f']
st = set(l2)
l1[:] = [33 for ele in l1 if ele in st]
print(l1)
```

Your code does not work as you are deleting elements from the list you are iterating. When you `del l[i]` you have changed the size of the list so what was at `l[i]` originally differs to what `l[i]` points to after you have removed an element. You should never delete elements from the list you are iterating over or as you see from your output the wrong elements can end up being removed.

If you start with your original list:

```
l1=['a','b','c', 'd']
index  0 == a
index 1 == b
index 2 == c
index 3 == d
```

Then if you remove `c` then `d` is at index `2` so you end up missing `d`.

You just need to add a print before and after deleting:

```
for (i, wor) in enumerate(l1):
    if wor in l2:
        l1[i] = 33
    else:
        print(l1[i],l1)
        del l1[i]
        print(l1[i],l1)

c [33, 33, 'c', 'd']
d [33, 33, 'd']
```

If you add `g` to l1 you will see a more obvious error:

```
l1=['a','b', "c", 'd',"g"]
l2= ['a','b','d','f'] 

for (i, wor) in enumerate(l1):
    if wor in l2:
        l1[i] = 33
    else:
        print(l1[i],l1)
        del l1[i]
        print(l1[i],l1)
print(l1)

c [33, 33, 'c', 'd', 'g']
d [33, 33, 'd', 'g']
g [33, 33, 'd', 'g']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File 
  ..........
    print(l1[i],l1)
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Because you have changed the size there no longer is an `l[4]`. Your code did not error only because the last element of l1 happened to be in l2.

Comment: I know there are other solutions that work, but I want to understand why my solution fails

Answer (score 1):

Padraic's solution seems like the way to go, but so you understand why yours is having problems, you are modifying the list that you are iterating over when you do the `del l1[i]` step.  That will change all the indexes on the next iteration of the loop, which won't likely do what you want it to.

Answer (score 1):

Why it doesn't work because you are iterating and deleting from the same list, `l1`

Consider the iteration when `wor = 'c'` here `i = 2`.

In this iteration since `'c'` is not present in the list, you are deleting from the list where by

`l1 = [33, 33, 'd']`, the new list.

Now the `enumerate` function has reached it end as there are no more indexes after `i=2` ( as the length of the list `l1` got shrunk due to the delete )

Answer (score 0):

In your code, the build_in function **del** deleted the specific value in that list. So the current size of the list was reduced by one **i.e** 3. Thus the loop ended.

Here is a sample code to differentiate the method:

```
l1=['a','b','c','d']
l2= ['a','b','d','f']    
i=0
for wor in l1:
    print wor
    if wor in l2:
        print 'id'
        l1[i]= 33
    else:
        #del l1[i]
        l1[i]=''
        print 'del'
    i+=1


print l1
print l2
```

> a
>
> b
>
> c
>
> del
>
> d
>
> [33, 33, '', 33]
>
> ['a', 'b', 'd', 'f']